# C# ASP .NET global variable for the whole application

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, global-variables

I want to instantiate an object at application start and want to maintain it until the application ends or I manually update it.

I thought I can do it with a `public static class` but it isn´t working. If I create this class:

```
public static class MyGlobalClass
{
   private static object _MyObject;

   static MyGlobalClass
   {
       _MyObject = new object();
   }

   public static object GetObject()
   {
       return _MyObject;
   }
}
```

And I create a aspx Page like:

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object obj = MyGlobalClass.GetObject();
    }
}
```

If I debug this example, on every request the static contructor is called, so the object `_MyObject` is initialized everytime and not just once like I thought.

The initialization of the object is expensive in my case so I want to instantiate it just once and only want to update it manually.

Do I have to tell ASP .NET to keep the `public static class` in memory? It seems ASP .NET throws the whole class `MyGlobalClass` away after each request.

## Update

Even the Application state is always empty:

```
public static class MyGlobalClass
{
   private static object _MyObject;

   static MyGlobalClass
   {
      if(HttpContext.Current.Application["MyObject"] != null)
      {
          _MyObject= (object)HttpContext.Current.Application["MyObject"];  
          return;  
      }
      _MyObject = new object();
      HttpContext.Current.Application["MyObject"] = _MyObject;
   }

   public static object GetObject()
   {
       return _MyObject;
   }
}
```

On every request the Application state is empty.

Answer (score -1):

There is a Pattern called Singleton, this might help you.

```
public class MyGlobalClass
{
    private static MyGlobalClass _instance;
    private static object _myObject;

    protected MyGlobalClass()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Application["MyObject"] != null)
        {
            _myObject = (object)HttpContext.Current.Application["MyObject"];
            return;
        }
        _myObject = new object();
        HttpContext.Current.Application["MyObject"] = _myObject;
    }

    public static MyGlobalClass GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new MyGlobalClass();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public static object GetObject()
    {
        return _myObject;
    }
}
```

You only need to call the GetInstance() Method for instantiate a new object of MyGlobalClass.

Comment: It does not help, because HttpContext.Current.Application["MyObject"] is always null so it will always be created new.

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work now but I don´t think it is a good approach:

I have to keep the static variable in my Global.asax file:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
   public static object MyObject { get; private set; }

   protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyObject = new object();
    }
}
```

Now I can access the object with Global.MyObject. The strange thing is that this should be the same as the first example with a custom static class, but the custom static class is always thrown away.

The last strange thing is why the `Application_Start` method is called 3 times. I set the Workerprocesses in the advanced settings of my Applicationpool to 1, so I don´t understand why `Application_Start` is called 3 times.

Anyway it is working, the object is initialized 3 times, because `Application_Start` is called 3 times, but after that, it can be used without beeing recreated. If I need to recreate it I do it manually with a static method in Global.asax.

## Update

The problem was simple but I did not know that before:
IIS restarts the Apppool everytime something changed in the bin folder. I created a new `AppDomain` for the global variable with `ShadowCopy` enabled with the cache folder as subfolder in bin. So everytime I created the `AppDomain` the bin folder changed and the Apppool restarted, so `Application_Start` was called more than once. I moved the cache directory outside from bin and now everything is working fine.